# 6.5 month old weight growth stalled

Tags: feeding, weight

She has been gaining roughly only 1 oz per week for the last 5 weeks. And obviously dropping in the percentile chart. Her total intake of milk (expressed breast milk in bottle) is about 20 oz per 24 hours, and at least half of the feedings is a struggle (takes in 2-3 oz, then stops, and have to try again in 30 mins and if we are lucky takes in another 2-3 oz). She does wake up 1-2 times at night for feeding.

She has no other signs of distress (except for waking of 5-6 times per night crying hard needing to be held).

Is this a reason for concern?

Comment: How old? I'd definitely mention it to the doctor at the next vaccination appointment, assuming that's in the next couple of weeks, but probably there is nothing to be concerned about. Also be careful that you don't overfeed her.

Comment: @Peter. She's 6.5 months old. Doc doesn't have anything to suggest and doesn't have an opinion whether we should be concerned. The most worrying is her last feeding before bed around 7:00pm, where she only takes in 3.5 oz, and would wake up in one hour hungry.

Comment: With 6.5 months you should not give her just breast milk. You must add food to her diet.

Comment: @Peter that's certainly not true. Solid foods should be introduced when the child is physically ready... this is *generally* around 6 months but not always. Regardless, the AAP recommends that infants under 1 year get most of their dietary needs met through breast milk. Solid food is extra and for "fun".

Comment: @Catija I admit, "must" was too strong a word. To put it in a more neutral way: The sources I know of recommend the introduction of solid foods at some point between 4 and 6 months. Among these, several recommend to start at 6 months, which is often based on the WHO recommendation that takes into account the danger of unclean water in 3rd world countries.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly normal. Weight gain can slow down as they get more active. Our child has gone through numerous plateaus and growth spurts. I would be more concerned if your child was dropping weight continuously. Our girl used to be in the 90th percentile for height and 50th percentile for weight. On our last visit to the doctor she was still in the 90th percentile for height (length), and dropped to around the 30th percentile for weight. The doctor told us this is perfectly normal, she is just "long and lean".